# resultado em codigo java

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldades num exercicio

O objetivo do exercicio era saber qual era a password quer iria dar como output .

usar esta como original "jU5t_a_sna_3lpm17ga45_u_4_mbrf4c" e através dos for-loops e byte arrays a baixo descobrir o resultado final! Mas não estou a conseguir chegar lá, será que alguém me podia ajudar?

```
public boolean checkPassword(String password) {
    if (password.length() != 32) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] buffer = new char[32];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        buffer[i] = password.charAt(i);
    }
    for (; i<16; i++) {
        buffer[i] = password.charAt(23-i);
    }
    for (; i<32; i+=2) {
        buffer[i] = password.charAt(46-i);
    }
    for (i=31; i>=17; i-=2) {
        buffer[i] = password.charAt(i);
    }
    String s = new String(buffer);
    return s.equals("jU5t_a_sna_3lpm17ga45_u_4_mbrf4c");
```

Comment: Você pode ver que tudo que esse método faz é trocar a ordem de algumas letras. Se você extrair um método que produz o `s` e alimentá-lo com a `String` dada no final, que é `"jU5t_a_sna_3lpm17ga45_u_4_mbrf4c"`, verá que a saída é `"jU5t_a_s1mpl3_an4gr4m_4_u_5baf7c"`, que é a resposta que você procura.

Comment: está correto Muito obrigado !!